# pandas aggregation on multiple string columns

Tags: python, pandas

below is  the source dataframe

```
a = [
    ['T1', 'R1', 1, 'a,b', 'E'],
    ['T1', 'R1', 2, 'c,d', 'F'],
    ['T1', 'R2', 1, 'e,f', 'G'],
    ['T1', 'R2', 4, 'g,h', 'H'],
    ['T2', 'R1', 1, 'i,j', 'I'],
    ['T2', 'R1', 1, 'k,l', 'J'],
    
]

df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns = ['t_id', 'r_id', 'al', 'mt', 'mt_type'])
```

group by to be done on t_id ,r_id  columns and aggregation to be done on these columns ['al', 'mt', 'mt_type']

result dataframe should look like this

```
    t_id r_id   al  mt        mt_type
0   T1  R1      2   a,b|c,d   E,F
1   T1  R2      4   e,f|g,h   G,H
2   T2  R1      1   i,j|k,l   I,J
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
aggregation_functions = {'al': 'max', 'mt': ' | '.join , 'mt_type': ' , '.join}
df_new = df.groupby(['t_id','r_id']).aggregate(aggregation_functions).reset_index()
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: which version of pandas does this apply for ?

Comment: Pandas version `0.24.2`.  Also, I have made some edits to match the output. Thanks